# C# - Error where cannot deserialize the current JSON array

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I want to display the list of state and city.

The following is the list for state and city that I've done:

```json
[
  { "State": "California", 
    "City": 
      ["Los Angeles", 
       "San Diego", 
       "San Francisco" 
      ]
   }, 
   { "State": "Texas", 
     "City": 
       ["Houston", 
        "San Antonio", 
        "Dallas"
       ]
    }
]
```

Here is my code

```
List<string> stateCities = new List<string>();
                var dictionary = stateCities.Select(x => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(x))
                     .ToDictionary(x => x["State"].ToString(), x => ((JArray)x["City"]).ToObject<List<string>>());

                    lookUpEditState.Properties.DataSource = dictionary;
                    lookUpEditState.Properties.ValueMember = "State";
                    lookUpEditCity.Properties.DataSource = dictionary;
                    lookUpEditCity.Properties.ValueMember = "City";
                    lookUpEditCity.CascadingOwner = lookUpEditState;
                }
```

i got this error:

> Fail to setup: Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type
> 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.
> To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List that can be deserialized from a JSON array.
> JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array. Path '', line 1, position 1.

Any idea how can i fix this? Thank you

Comment: From the error message, it sounds like you expect a JSON object, but you're trying to deserialize a JSON array. Without the JSON producing the problem, I don't see how we can provide any extra help.

Comment: my go to way to deserialize a JSON is to get a sample output, use any online json to c# class converter, then deserialize using that class instead of casting it into a dictionary like that

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama may i know more explanation about this? i dont really understand. thank you

Comment: To simplify the exception message: When you want to deseriialize json to a Dictionary your json string must not start with `[` - but it does

Comment: Well, how can we help with a problem deserializing JSON when you don't provide JSON? You're expecting an object (a dictionary is represented by JSON.NET in JSON as an object), but your JSON is seemingly an array (a list of objects or values) based on the error message.

Comment: @encryptoferia That functionality is built into Visual Studio too (Edit | Paste Special | Paste as JSON classes).

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama Well, he did but as an image

Comment: @SirRufo Oh, I missed that. Another reason why providing important details as images isn't a good way to go, I guess.

Comment: @SirRufo then what should i change the "[" with inside my sql server since it wont save if i put "{" symbol. thank you

Comment: please read https://json.org to understand the meaning of json

Answer (score 2):

You need to deserialize JSON using a class that matches its representation. In this case you have an array of objects that have a State and City property, so you could use this:

```
var template = new [] { new { State = "", City = new string[] {} }};
var array = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(jsonText, template);
```

You could then convert it to a dictionary if you really want:

```
var dictionary = array.ToDictionary( x => x.State, y => y.City );
```

...which will give you a `Dictionary<string,string[]>`.

Comment: I just learn that it will be more easier if i get the array using object instead of string. May I know how can i get and add the state and city from my database? This is my current code but it still cant get the state and city value:

Comment: Dictionary<string, List<string>> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
List<StateCity> stateCity = new List<StateCity>();
List<string> state;
List<string> city;
DataTable dtStateCity = _DBSet.GetDataTable("SELECT * FROM StateCity", false, null);
foreach (DataRow dr in dtStateCity.Rows)
{dictionary.Add(System.DataConvert.MyToString(dr["StateCity"]), new List<string>() { "City" });}
dictionary = stateCity.ToDictionary(s => s.state, c => c.city);
state = new List<string>(dictionary.Keys);
lookUpEditState.Properties.DataSource = state;

Comment: Can't really read that. Feel free to ask a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me

```
  Dictionary<string, List<string>> dictionary = JArray.Parse(json)
                        .ToDictionary(ja => (string)ja["State"],ja => ja["City"]
                        .Select(i => (string)i).ToList());
```